# Artifactory: how to add properties to a build run?

Tags: artifactory

For a build run in artifactory, exists a tab named "Environment" which contains a section named "System Variables".

Link to image: [Environment tab with variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Do8m.png)

I need to add some properties there via REST API or artifactoy groovy public api (PAPI).

I managed to create build info with properties (via REST API), but now I need to update it with the properties. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The Environment tab is created according to the build-info JSON deployed to Artifactory using the /api/build REST API. The build-info structure is available at the build-info github project's README file here:
https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info
When building the JSON you can add properties to it, by adding them to the "properties" section as described in the the above README. This is probably how you added the properties to the build run.
The build-info for a specific build run however is immutable in Artifactory and cannot be modified after it is deployed.